# How to write getters and setters for MessageId variable in java?

Tags: java

I am working on one of the projects. I am mapping JSON to Java object. but in json, one field is started with a capital letter as (MessageId). So I am not able to write proper getter and setter who map MessageId automatically. So can anyone suggest me a proper way?
My getters and setter are as below:-

```
public String getMessageId() {
    return MessageId;
}

public void setMessageId(String messageId) {
    MessageId = messageId;
}
```

Comment: would be helpful if you can add what is used for JSON mapping. (For example maybe Jackson, or Gson ?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `Jackson` then you can annotate that field with `MessageId` and `Jackson` will do the rest for you, e.g.:

```
@JsonProperty("MessageId")
private String messageId;

//getters and setters
```

Here's the [documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html).

Comment: Thanks Darshan, This is my expected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@JsonProperty("MessageId")` annotation on methods.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your field `MessageId` to `messageId` let your Getter/ Setter as is and add `@JsonProperty("MessageId")` to your field `messageId`